# react setState doesn't update array value by index

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

does anybody know why updating specific index value like this doesn't work ?

```
const [results, setResults] = useState([...Array(data.length)].map(e => []));

const updateResults = (index, value) => { //value is for sur an array of one dimension
    let newArray = results;
    newArray[index] = value
    console.log(newArray) //verifying that it is OK (works well)
    setResults(newArray) //has no effect
}
```

Comment: how about updating state by `setResults([...newArray])` ?

Comment: oh my god you're a genious, thought `...` was only for objects, and not for array

Comment: it's because in your manner, you are just mutating the previous value and react doesn't recognize any update in the state. in order to update your state, you need to pass new array to `setResults` method.

Comment: `...` works for array and objecst. Here you can read more about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses `Object.is` under the hood so that it knows when to re-render the component. To overcome this, use:

```js
const [results, setResults] = useState([...Array(data.length)].map(e => []));

const updateResults = (index, value) => {
    let newArray = [...results]; // Object.is(results, newArray) will return false
    newArray[index] = value
    console.log(newArray)
    setResults(newArray)
}
```